# apt upgrade issue after update from 20.04 to 22.04

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

I'm not able to run apt upgrade after updating from 20.04 to 22.04 (ubuntu server), can you help me with fixing that?
Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same error.

I wasnt able to hit any of the repos when running `apt update`

After checking my `/etc/resolv.conf`  I saw that  only tailscale nameserver was there.

Adding googles name server  `nameserver 8.8.8.8` fixed that.  My problem is solved.

If that doesnt work try adding their other one.  `nameserver 8.8.4.4`